# Matplotlib title on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

instead of on the top of a plot, is it possible to place title on the side of a plot, that is, beside y-axis?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))

plt.title('Center Title')
plt.title('Left Title', loc='left')
plt.title('Right Title', loc='right')

plt.show()
```

In this demo from matplotlib tutorial, title can only be placed on top. But I need it at y axis. How I can get that?

I can obviously do a

```
axes[i].set_title("Foo", rotation='vertical', x=-.3, y=0.2)
```

and place title anywhere, though.

Comment: What remains as an issue after setting it with set_title()? I am not sure about the desired output.

Comment: @r-beginners: the only issue is if this is the only way to do that, or if there is an arument-way to set title on y axis.

Comment: This method also allows me to set the title. `fig.suptitle('fig-title', x=0, y=1)`

Comment: Newer matplotlib have supylabel and supxlabel.  Of course there’s x/ylabel for single axes.